# ImageView Array returns null object

Tags: android

I am trying to create same ImageView 20 times in different locations, I am using this code:

```
    rand = new Random();
    ImageView[] imageViewArray = new ImageView[20];
    ArrayList<Float> xarray = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> yarray = new ArrayList<>();
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    layoutwidth = size.x;
    layoutheight = size.y;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " " + layoutwidth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).
            show();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(this);
        imageViewArray[i].setTag(i);
        imageViewArray[i].setImageResource(R.mipmap.enemy);
        randx = rand.nextInt(layoutwidth + 1);
        randy = rand.nextInt(layoutheight + 1);
        imageViewArray[i].setX(randx);
        imageViewArray[i].setY(randy);
        xarray.add(imageViewArray[i].getX());
        yarray.add(imageViewArray[i].getY());
        rlt.addView(imageViewArray[i]);
    }
```

Eventually, My app crashes at line `rlt.addView(imageViewArray[i]);` and says it is a null object, here is my logcat:

```
09-12 14:15:19.941  20395-20395/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: firstappdevelopment.thatdoskilledme, PID: 20395
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{firstappdevelopment.thatdoskilledme/firstappdevelopment.thatdoskilledme.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
            at firstappdevelopment.thatdoskilledme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
```

I don't know why it returns null as I created it inside the `for` statement, can anyone please help me, thank you :)

Comment: what is rlt in you code ?

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia ohhh.. I switched from getting layout size to getting screen size and accidentally deleted the line initializes the layout, thank you oops :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. make sure you declare relative layout properly.
2. You don't have to take array of image view because all element have same bitmap so define another xml file that contain your image view and each time add that xml layout view to relative layout !

Comment: nice idea, I will try it maybe.